# security with asp.net mvc 4 web api

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I've created my first mvc 4 project using the web api template. I've configured CORS to restrict other sites from accessing my api directly into other websites. I use ajax to retrieve the data supplied by the api into a web page and that works well.

The address to my web api is http://www.xyz.com/webapi/  one of the actions is http://www.xyz.com/webapi/api/sales  How can I prevent anyone from accessing /webapi and /webapi/api/sales and using the data (screen scraping) for their own use. I do not want any other service browser accessing the web api, just the ajax query that is present on another website that I've set up.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this is the homework to be done: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security

Answer (score 0):

### Approach 1 - Get a Bearer Token

You could implement this - [Individual Accounts in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/authentication/individual-accounts-in-aspnet-web-api)

Here in this tutorial, the controllers are marked with `[Authorize]` and the following steps are followed.

- [Register a User](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/authentication/individual-accounts-in-aspnet-web-api#register)
- [Authenticate and Get a Bearer Token](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/authentication/individual-accounts-in-aspnet-web-api#authenticate)
- [Send an Authorized Request](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/authentication/individual-accounts-in-aspnet-web-api#authorize)

### Approach 2 - Use a private API Key

You could use an api key with each of your web api calls and check on server side if the api key is valid if not return 401, Unauthorized. This api key could be saved in your web.config file.